# cascade deletions in many-to-many relationships when no related items are present

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, cascading-deletes

I have a schema that looks roughly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    txt TEXT,
);
CREATE TABLE tags(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE posts_tags(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I want to delete a post with a specified ID, but I also want to delete all the tags related to that post that don't have any other posts associated.

So, assuming there's only one post about programming, the `"programming"` tag should be gone when that post is deleted. However, if there are multiple posts about, let's say, `sports`, deleting one should keep the tag intact and only delete the appropriate relationship from the `posts_tags` table (I assume this is done automatically by cascade).

I know I can just select all the tags, loop over them using my programming language of choice, verify if they only have one associated post and delete them, but I'm looking for a simpler solution that works with SQL.

I will need to do this for multiple tables so copy/pasting the code multiple times would be inefficient.

Is there any way to do this?

I've researched many to many relationships and deleting but all I've found was a mention about using triggers. However, I don't really have any idea about what trigger should I use.

Comment: Shouldn't your `post_tags` table have a column that is a foreign key referencing `posts(id)`? Especially if you want rows to be automatically deleted when a post is? That won't happen the way it is now.

Answer (score 2):

The schema appears to be your issue, basically the **post_tags** table appears to be useless as it is, but with a column for referencing/relating/mapping to the post it becomes useful as a much used mapping/reference/relationship table.

I think you would want a schema like :-

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    txt TEXT,
);
CREATE TABLE tags(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE posts_tags(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then you are tying tags to posts, if a post is deleted then all rows for that post will be removed other posts using that tag will remain. Should a tag be deleted then all rows that use that tag will be deleted.

P.S. you could do away with the id column and you may then wish to have the PRIMARY KEY as a composite of both columns thus eliminating useless/confusing duplicate rows.

So perhaps use (with the other tow tables) :-

```
CREATE TABLE posts_tags(
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id,post_id)
);
```

Or if the version of sqlite supports it (3.8.2+) :-

```
CREATE TABLE  posts_tags(
        tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        post_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY (tag_id,post_id) 
        )
    WITHOUT ROWID
    ;
```